# catalog/seo_sitemap/category/ showing *disabled* categories

Tags: catalog, seo, sitemaps

On Magento 1.9.0.1

catalog/seo_sitemap/category/ showing *disabled* categories

Hi we have a link to catalog/seo_sitemap/category/ in our store view

the problem is that is shows the DISABLED categories from our store domain (higher level in hierarchy) when the categories are disabled on store view level.

---

Working as expected

```
Category 1 works like expected
Default config = enabled yes
  store view A = inherit
  store view B = inherit
```

Not working as expected

```
Category 2 something strange going on
Default config = enabled yes
  store view A = inherit
  store view B = override, disable
```

But category 2 in store view B is *still* visible

Help appreciated: thanks!

---

Example

This is what we see in frontend
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMRFb.png)

And this is what we see in backend
[image]

question: is this a Magento code error? or how can we solve this

Comment: Are you indexes up to date?

Comment: yes they are. I don't know if you tested the set-up but it really looks like a bug. We made a report of it anyways for Magento 1.9.x - thanks Marius!

Comment: I haven't tested. I just commented the first thing that came to mind. But now I will test. Usually I don't use the default sitemap provided by Magento. I have my own page for that.

Comment: FYI: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/680 and http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible fix: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/commit/5f2eae6992b597a945e35f169000b383740cd4de

And why it is important http://youtu.be/hi5DGOu1uA0

Comment: #59 doesn't seem to do the trick, try #485 https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/485

Answer (score 2):

I'll add the relevant comment as an answer:

As per https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/680:

> **Magento Team** |posted 4/18/15 6:24 PM
>
> The sitemaps are no longer recommended for use given Google's use of sitemap.xml. We don't expect to fix this issue in the near future.